Couldn't start the nestjs application on render.com platform
I have a nestjs application which i have deployed on render.com platform. It was working fine. Whenever I was merging my PR to master branch so pipeline was automatically deploying nestjs application to render and start the application. But, today, I merged another PR of mine to the master branch and this time application was started successfully but somehow stopped right after successfully start and throwing an error of route not found.
Here is the deployment logs that is is visible in render console


==> Cloning from https://github.com/fahadsubzwari924/cwc-nest
==> Checking out commit b542fac01f34a110b449188a575a8d595613f370 in branch master
==> Downloading cache...
==> Transferred 231MB in 8s. Extraction took 5s.
==> Using Node version 20.12.2 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running build command 'npm install; npm run build'...
up to date, audited 886 packages in 4s
133 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
18 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 10 high, 3 critical)
To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
> nest-server@0.0.1 prebuild
> rimraf dist
> nest-server@0.0.1 build
> nest build
==> Uploading build...
==> Build uploaded in 8s
==> Build successful 
==> Deploying...
==> Using Node version 20.12.2 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running 'npm run start:prod'
> nest-server@0.0.1 start:prod
> node dist/main
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] DashboardModule dependencies initialized +105ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +90ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:28 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:29 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +600ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:29 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] FileModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +8157ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] CustomerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] OrderSourceModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] OrderModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ReportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ProductModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/api/v1}: +244ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] ProductController {/api/v1/products}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products/search, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products, POST} route +89ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/products/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] CustomerController {/api/v1/customers}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers/search, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/customers/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] OrderController {/api/v1/orders}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders/:id/pdf, GET} route +94ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders/:id, PUT} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/orders/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] UserController {/api/v1/users}: +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/users, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/users/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/users, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] AuthController {/api/v1/auth}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/auth/login, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] FileController {/api/v1/files}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/files/upload, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] ReportController {/api/v1/reports}: +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/reports, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/reports/dashboard/stats, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] OrderSourceController {/api/v1/order-sources}: +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/order-sources, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/order-sources/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/order-sources, POST} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/order-sources/:id, PUT} route +1ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/order-sources/:id, DELETE} route +0ms
[Nest] 104  - 09/20/2024, 4:52:37 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +8ms
--Exception-- undefined
exception:  NotFoundException: Cannot HEAD /
    at callback (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:77:19)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at cors (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15) {
  response: { statusCode: 404, message: 'Cannot HEAD /', error: 'Not Found' },
  status: 404,
  options: {}
}
request method: HEAD request url/ {"statusCode":404,"timestamp":"2024-09-20T16:52:38.532Z","path":"/","method":"HEAD","errorName":"NotFoundException","message":"Cannot HEAD /"}
==> Your service is live 
--Exception-- undefined
exception:  NotFoundException: Cannot GET /
    at callback (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:77:19)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:328:13)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at cors (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15) {
  response: { statusCode: 404, message: 'Cannot GET /', error: 'Not Found' },
  status: 404,
  options: {}
}
request method: GET request url/ {"statusCode":404,"timestamp":"2024-09-20T16:52:40.675Z","path":"/","method":"GET","errorName":"NotFoundException","message":"Cannot GET /"}
==> Detected service running on port 10000
==> Docs on specifying a port: https://render.com/docs/web-services#port-binding



And now when I try from postman or from my front-end application, service is unreachable.
I try to build, start the application with prod credentials of db and all that so it's building and running fine at my local. And please note, previously in this same setup this application and deployment process was working fine. I am facing this issue for the first time. By the way, here is the PR that I merged today after which, the issue started happening

can you add the package.json flle and main.ts

Issue has been resolved by Render's team. They restarted my server by themself and it's now working. They didn't informed me the exact issue.

Great, If you can get the change from render team. add it as the answer
